# Convert nchar column to nvarchar and Trim whitespace

Tags: sql

Could someone please help me with this?

I need to convert an nchar column to an nvarchar column and trim the whitespace.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT RTrim(CAST([MynCharColumn] As nVarChar))
```

Comment: You need to give a length for nvarchar, else you can truncate the data (defaults to 30 if not specified like this!)

Comment: To do that, I'd need to know the length of the nChar column.

Answer (score 7):

```
declare @foo nchar(32)
select @foo = '   Hello, World   '
select ltrim(rtrim(convert(nvarchar(32), @foo)))
```